# Casting sibling class with a good reason?

Tags: c++, polymorphism, siblings, static-cast

I have a **Base** class and a lot of derived classes (i.e. **DerivedX**) as production code.
Without touching those classes I make a **BaseExt** class deriving from Base in order to manipulating internal data for testing purposes.

```
+-----------+            +-----------+
| Base      + <- - - - - | BaseExt   |
+-----------+            +-----------+
   /|\
    |
+-----------+
| DerivedX  +
+-----------+
```

Here is the code example

```
      class Base {
      public:
        int data() const { return _data; }
      protected:
        Base() = default;
        virtual ~Base() = default;
        int _data;
      };

      class Derived1 : public Base {
      };

      class BaseExt : public Base {
      public:
        void inject_data(int data) { _data = data; }
      };
```

It works intuitively to me.

```
    std::shared_ptr<Base> p = std::make_shared<Derived1>();
    auto d1 = p->data(); // 0
    std::static_pointer_cast<BaseExt, Base>(p)->inject_data(10);
    auto d2 = p->data(); // 10
```

Baseline: I don't want to change my production code (i.e. Base and DerivedX)

Of course I could extend **Derived1** to do the same job, however I have a lot of such derived classes which add too much code for just a simple task.

the question is

- is it reasonable to cast into sibling class for this use case?
- how to make it safe? (e.g. no attribute in the sibling class)
- any better and concise solution (except modifying Base and DereivedX classes)

Comment: The safer way is to create a `friend` function for this.

Comment: Why is it intuitive, you cast instance of type Derived1, to some other type BaseExt. What if BaseExt had some data member?

Comment: @Zefick a friend function in Base class? but modifying Base and DereivedX classes would be the last option

Comment: @marcinj ja, that is exactly my question! is it reasonable to do such cast with some condition? i.e. no extra attributes in the sibling class.

Comment: I don't think there is a safe way to do your hack without modifications of `Base`/`DerivedX`.

Comment: Does `Base` contains virtual method ? or `Base` can be a [StandardLayout](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/StandardLayoutType) class (and so `memcpy` could be used) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about a template?

```
template<typename T>
struct TestableDerived : T {

    inject_data(int data) {
        _data = data;
    }

    static std::shared_ptr<Base> createAndInjectData(int data) {
        std::shared_ptr<TestableDerived<T>> ptr = std::make_shared<TestableDerived<T>>();
        ptr->inject_data(data);
        return ptr;
    }
}
```

Alternatively, if you're prepared to change your source such that each derived class virtually inherits from `Base` (i.e. `class DerivedX : public virtual Base`), then I think you can mix this with multiple inheritance to just get 'an extra method during testing' (I haven't tested this):

```
struct BaseExt : virtual Base {
    void inject_data(int data) { _data = data; }
}

template<typename T>
struct TestDerived<T> : virtual T, virtual BaseExt {}

void doSomeTesting() {
    std::shared_ptr<TestDerived<DerivedX>> p1 = std::make_shared<TestDerived<DerivedX>>();
    std::shared_ptr<DerivedX> p2 = p1;
    std::shared_ptr<BaseExt> p3 = p1;

    assert(p1->data()==0);
    assert(p2->data()==0);
    assert(p3->data()==0);

    p3->inject_data(10);

    assert(p1->data()==10);
    assert(p2->data()==10);
    assert(p3->data()==10);
}
```